Telegram bot not answering / not replying to me
Please help. I watched YouTube video. How to make TG bot by Python and Aiogram in Visual Studio Code. After I entered python main.py in terminal - nothing changed, so my bot is quiet when I typing something to it.
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command


bot = Bot(token='*token API code*')
dp = Dispatcher()


@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Привет!')
    await message.reply('Как дела?')

@dp.message(Command('help'))
async def cmd_help(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Вы нажали на кнопку помощи')

@dp.message(F.text == 'У меня всё хорошо')
async def nice(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Я очень рад')


async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == '__mane__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Бот выключен')

This is how it is looking in VS Code

if __name__ == '__mane__':

Should be
if __name__ == '__main__':

